# Liferay 6.2 portlet custom roles

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I have created a custom Regular Role and I have inserted it inside portlet.xml of so-portlet(security-role-ref element) and I have also mapped it with the respective role in liferay-portlet.xml. 
However, when a user owns only this custom Regular Role, an error message is displayed "You do not have the roles required to access this portlet". 
It is also strange that this happens only in user's personal site, on any other site user is able to view the specific portlet.

Does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Can you check the settings / permissions for that specific portlet instance ?  These settings are overriding the portal's permissions and the Portlet's default permissions

Comment: I am using the social office theme where the so-portlet is embedded in theme. By default, in sidebar_portlets.vm the portlet preferences are set like this $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("displayStyle", "0")
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders", "false")

Comment: Is it possible to change these portlet permissions(e.g. which roles can view this portlet) programmaticaly?

Comment: hmm that's not what I meant :) I've posted an answer for your. No, you shouldn't edit roles programmatically, you should use the provided interface.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a Custom Regular Role for your App, you should edit the default Role Permissions

1. log as an admin
2. Go to `Control Panel`, `Roles`,
3. Find your Role, and from the `Actions` menu on the right side, pick `Define Permissions`
4. From the left menu, find your application
5. Edit your permissions. Make sure to have the 'View' action granted for your Role. You can additionally, allow it for all sites (default), or you can just select the 'User Personal Site'
   [image]

Now, if you want to make an exception for a specific portlet instance (that's what I meant in my question, in the comments) you can:

1. Log as Admin
2. Navigate to the specific Page where your portlet instance is added.
3. Enable Edit Controls, and edit your portlet (mini menu on the upper right side, with the wrench icon)
4. Pick `permissions` and have your Role allowed to view the portlet

Comment: Your answer is correct and it should have been applied in my case, but the portlet I'm talking about is the so-portlet[user_bar, sites - 2 different portlets within so-portlet] which is not available in this Applications list - as it is not also available in the 'Add Applications' list in the left sidebar of each site page.

Answer (score 0):

The Personal Site is a Private Site if I remember well, so i think your user is not a site member, necessary condition to view the private pages.

Comment: Yes, but my user is actually able to view the page where this portlet is located, and can also view normally some other portlets on the same page.